# multipart/form-data request to FastAPI giving 422 response

Tags: python, python-requests, multipartform-data, fastapi

I have this POST request

```
params = dict(converter=converter, cmd_options=cmd_options)
with open(zip_filename, 'rb') as fp:
    files = {'file': fp}
    result = requests.post(server_url,
            data=params,
            files=files)
```

going to this FastAPI method:

```
@app.post("/convert")
def convert(converter: str = Form(...), cmd_options: str = Form(...), file: bytes = File(...)):
```

This gives a **422 Unprocessable Entity** reponse.

I tried to specify `converter`
and `cmd_options` as string typs (without `Form()`) but then the values of both parameters are empty.

Any idea?